# Flutter How to save the images from multi image picker

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm building a form and there an option to include image and using for that [multi_image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker) package, now the app is offline using SQLite, now that plugin just there 2 ways to access the image throw `AssetThumb` widget or getting the image byte data and make it work with `Image.memory(imageByte.buffer.asUint8List())`.

I need to know how to save the selected images into my app locally? do I save the images on custom directory on my app or saving the buffer on my database.

Comment: Have you figured out a way to do it?